# Nodejs UDP/dgram transmission rate

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

I have a code which send packets to random destination and I need to calculate transmission rate of the packet. At this part i am a little blocked because i don't know how to do it, or if it is some modules which do this measurement?
Some tips or guidance are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean "transmission rate"? As in packets per unit of time? Keep a counter and a stopwatch.

Comment: @tadman transmission rate in kbps or Mbps, which i send in an unit of time, those are the requirements imposed by the professor.

Comment: Then figure out how much data you're sending in terms of kilobits and divide by time.